# Serial port (AT commands) constantly streams a single byte or ERROR

Tags: c, serial-port, at-command

I am trying to read data from a serial port from my BananaPi (Debian jessie). I wrote this code:

```
typdef struct write_args {
    int fd;
} write_args;

/* Thread to wait for user input */
void* serial_write_fn(void* args)
{
    write_args* wargs = (write_args*)args);
    char buf[256];
    while (1) {
        memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);

        n = write(wargs->fd, buf, strlen(buf));
        if (n < 0) {
            fputs("write() failed.\n", stderr);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void serial()
{
    int fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCCTY | O_NDELAY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open port failed.");
        return;
    }

    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

    /* Create write thread */
    write_args wargs;
    wargs.fd = fd;
    pthread_t tid;
    int err = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &serial_write_fn, &wargs);
    if (err != 0)
        perror("Failed to create thread.");

    char buffer[512];
    while (1) {
        memset(buffer, 0, 512);
        ssize_t bytes = read(fd, buffer, 512);

        if (bytes > 1) /* Try to remove this line */
            printf(buffer);
    }

    close(fd);
}
```

So when I run the program, naturally it created the write thread an waits for input. Then, I type `AT` and `AT+VCID=1` and I get both times `OK` as an answer:

```
AT
OK
AT+VCID=1
OK
```

Then, I tried to call the number to see the output and I got

```
RING
DATE = 0722
TIME = 0441
NMBR = 6982311133
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR
...
```

That's the first problem. The second problem is that when I try to remove that last if ( `if (bytes > 1)` ) the `read` function never stops reading data. It always return 1 byte.

Am I doing something wrong? Why do I keep getting ERROR and why `read` function always has 1 byte to read?

**EDIT #1**

So after MartinJames's comment, I decided to investigate a little more.

I changed my read loop to this:

```
while (1) {
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    bytes = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (bytes == 0) {
        printf("Read 0 bytes.\n");
        break;
    } else if (bytes == -1) {
        printf("Read -1 bytes.\n");
        break;
    } else if (bytes == 1) {
        printf("Read 1 bytes.\n");
    } else {
        printf(buf);
    }
}
```

The program run and waited for me to write a command. I wrote *at* and as you can see, the read function returns 1 byte everytime, except a few OKs now and and then.

```
thecrafter@bananapi:~/serial$ sudo make run
Executing bin/Debug/serial.out ...
at <--- I typed that and clicked Enter
at
Read 1 bytes.
Read 1 bytes.
OK
Read 1 bytes.
Read 1 bytes.
atat
Read 1 bytes.
Read 1 bytes.
Read 1 bytes.
Read 1 bytes.
Read 1 bytes.
Read 1 bytes.
Read 1 bytes.
OK
Read 1 bytes.
Read 1 bytes.
...
```

Comment: ' why read function always has 1 byte to read?' - how do you know that?  What if read() returns 0 or -1?  If -1, what would errno/GetLastError() show as the issue?  Really, you need to get better at debugging than this:((

Comment: 'ERROR' is being returned by your modem.

Comment: @MartinJames I will investigate the read() statement and update my answer. As for the "ERROR", I know that it is being returned by my modem but I do not know why. When I use a different client for AT commands (minicom open source program) I don't get those errors.

Comment: @MartinJames I updated the answer with proof that read function always has 1 byte to read. I think that's weird.

Comment: *"...that's weird."* -- Not really.  Your program never configures the serial terminal (but should), so you're at the mercy of whatever the previous configuration was.  In this case it seems to be raw mode rather than canonical mode.  Reboot the system, and the terminal *may* default to canonical mode, and then you'd read a whole line at a time.  Stop rolling the dice, and configure the serial terminal.  See [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that sawdust was right for pointing out I should read [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html) more carefully.

The configuration that fixed my problem is:

```
struct termios opt;
tcgetattr(fd, &opt);
opt->c_cflag     |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
opt->c_lflag     &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
opt->c_oflag     &= ~OPOST;
opt->c_cc[VMIN]  = 1;
opt->c_cc[VTIME] = 10;
tcsetattr(fd, TCSADRAIN, &opt);
```

Comment: That initialization is incomplete.  It only configures the terminal for non-canonical mode.  The framing parameters (i.e. baudrate, frame size, parity, number of stop bits) are still left to chance.

Comment: @sawdust In the link you provided it says `Next you need to establish communications with the MODEM. The best way to do this is by sending the "AT" command to the MODEM. This also allows smart MODEMs to detect the baud you are using. When the MODEM is connected correctly and powered on it will respond with the response "OK".` so I figured it's enough to use that configuration. If it isn't, how can I find the correct baudrate, partity, etc.. ?

Comment: *"how can I find the correct baudrate, partity, etc.. ?"* -- You have to match the configuration of the connected device.  Normally that is documented in a manual, or retrievable from the device or the person who set it up.  In your case, since you seem to have a working connection, get a configuration report using the `stty -a -F /dev/ttyACM0` shell command.

Comment: @sawdust That's awesome!! Thanks a lot. I'll update & accept my answer when I get the configuration right. Thanks.